# How to detect the :utf8 open pragma (or any conversions for the file-handles)?

Tags: perl, utf-8

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6806310/632407) I asked about the problem with encoding and `open pragma`. Based on @[daxim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806310/plackup-access-log-locale-and-open-pragma-encoding-problem/6807082#6807082) coming to my mind another questions.

```
use open qw(:std :utf8);
```

- It is a good practice using the above `open pragma`? Asking because I cannot ensure than some CPAN packages does not want do some IO - and the `open pragma` will interfere with them.

sub-questions:

- Is possible somewhat detect, what pragma is in effect for the given stream? For example: is possible somewhat detect than STDOUT is opened with the `open(:std :utf8)` pragma?
- more broadly, is possible detect what conversions/(or encoding) is applied for any (already opened) file-handle? (if so, it is possible to ensure not getting double encoding.)

*Ps: I learned much from the [tchrit's famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129), but seem not enough yet. ;(*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PerlIO::get_layers](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html#Querying-the-layers-of-filehandles) to detect layers assigned to a filehandle:

```
use open qw(:std :utf8);
open my $in, '<', 'somefile' or die "$!"
my @layers = PerlIO::get_layers($in);      # ("unix", "crlf", "utf8")
```